# Combining text and JS in className after a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm having trouble combining a text and CSS style after for className after a ternary/conditional. I've looked at so many different examples however nothing seems to be working.

```
<div className={key === active ? ({ 'column ' + styles.Active}) : ('column ')} key={key}>
```

Can anyone please show me how to best format this correctly? I need both the column and styles.Active classNames to appear if key === active.

Thank you in advance

Comment: <div className={key === active ? ( 'column ' + styles.Active ) : ('column ')} key={key}>
this should work

Comment: `<div className={'column ' + (key === active ? styles.Active : '')} key={key}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the same solution, but the best approach

```
<div className={key === active ? `column ${styles.Active}` : 'column'}>
```

it's more readable, self explaining, and discreet, this is how you should write the code, not the otherway..

className expects a string and instead you gave it an object {'column ' + styles.Active} which is wrong.

also, i don't understand your logic. styles.Active would be an **object** which is of a **style**(style object). if that's the case you are doing it wrong again..

```
<div className="column" style={key === active ? styles.Active : {}}>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with adding an npm package you can use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

```
import classNames from 'classnames';

...

<div className={classNames('column', { [styles.Active]: key === active })} key={key}>
```

=================

if you don't want to add an npm package

```js
<div className={'column ' + (key === active ? styles.Active : '')} key={key}>
```

Answer (score 1):

For readability it may be better to extract this into a variable. Though, the ternary could easily be inline.

**String Literals**

*For those that prefer ES6+*

```
// Ternary
const className = `column ${(key === active) ? styles.Active : ''}`;

// Or a little more readable
const className = 'column';

if (key === active) {
  className += ` ${styles.Active}`;
}

...
  <div className={className} key={key}>
```

**Concatenation**

*It seems for the moment string concatenation is faster: ([https://jsperf.com/es6-string-literals-vs-string-concatenation/49)](https://jsperf.com/es6-string-literals-vs-string-concatenation/49)_)*

```
// Ternary
const className = 'column' + ((key === active) ? ' ' + styles.Active : '')}`;

// Or a little more readable
const className = 'column';

if (key === active) {
  className += ' ' + styles.Active;
}

...
  <div className={className} key={key}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one out. Take the column out , and have the ternary operated on just the key

```
<div className={'column ' + (key === active ? styles.Active : '')} key={key}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do it use an array and join it, it's bit old question but maybe it gonna help someone else.

```
className={ [ isMobile ? 'small' : 'large' , darkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light' , isSomething ? 'classX' : 'classY' ].join(' ') }
```